# Remove index.html from url in Weebly without .htaccess file

Tags: url, duplicates, html, weebly

I want to remove "index.html" from the homepage URL of Weebly site without .htaccess file, please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Weebly does not currently provide the option to redirect /index.html to the root domain URL or give you the access needed to properly make those changes, however, links to your home page (at least on your website) should be going to the domain-root.com and not /index.html so you should be ok there.

Keep in mind that index.html is a file, that exists as the home page for the folder your website pages live in, and you can't remove it from it's existence(at least on Weebly).

So, the thing to do would be to submit it to Weebly as a Feature Request and request that they make the necessary changes on their end, for the sake of ALL Weebly users! ;) 
https://community.weebly.com/t5/Vote-on-Features/idb-p/IdeaExchange